# Convert an array of ids to a csv string with quotes

Tags: apex, soql, webservices, data-types

I have a webservice method that takes the $_REQUEST from the URL parameter of my app and I believe handles it like an array, for example:

```
inputs.param1 = "some_value"
inputs.param2 = "1209845, 2348425876, 2958263459, etc"
```

> In Chrome developer tools it looks like this

[image]

But now I need to use the "Ids" parameter to make up a dynamic SOQL query in the `WHERE` statement. I assume I can get the parameter from my `inputs` variable by referring to the *ids* attribute of the variable like this

```
inputs.ids
```

Which should equate to `"####, ####, ####"`, but I am not sure if SF considers this an `<Array>` or a `<String>`.

Either way, I need to convert this parameter to a `<String>` with each Id # wrapped in single-quotes. So that I can have a WHERE statement like this work: `WHERE Id IN :ids`

Comment: you are using dynamic soql or static (compiled) soql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for how the controller sees it, I believe you can pass a Javascript array to the controller during remote methods if the signature of the remote method is using a String[]. If it is just using a string then the array will be passed as a string.

Typically you would take the string, split it into an array and use it in the sql:

i.e.

```
String s = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';

String[] string_array = s.split(',');
```

then you use it in the sql

dynamic:

```
'Select ID From Account where field in :string_array';
```

or regular

```
[Select ID From Account where field in :string_array];
```

Comment: What if I needed to add 2 objects from my input together? For example: `String[] starting_id = inputs.first_id+',';` _(which is not an array, just a string)_ AND `String[] string_ids = inputs.ids.split(',');`